# How to make properties file in netbeans

Tags: java, properties, struts2, netbeans-6.9

i am working on a struts2 web application-project and using netbeans 6.9. i want to create a properties file for my project. 
how do i do that in net-beans........

Answer (score 16, accepted):

right click on the location where you would like to add property file.

```
new > other > other >  Properties file
```